# Flattening a list of lists to a set with exceptions in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, nested-lists

This feels like a peculiar problem and I am very new to Scala, so I don't know how to ask the right questions in order to get progress on this problem.

As a demonstration, say I have a list of lists like this:

```
val data = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(2, 3, 4))
```

and I want to be able to reduce it down to a List of integers that looks mostly like a distinct set of the multiple lists, with one exception: where each list has more than one of each integer, I want to represent that in the final list. So as a general rule, the list with the most representations of that integer will have "their" repetitions of that integer in the final list. So that would ideally give:

```
List(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)
```

I know I can do `data.flatten.distinct` and get:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

but that's not what I want and I know there's probably a bit more work to get to the desired result.

I am wondering if there is a good way to achieve the desired result in a functional way in scala.

Comment: You have to tell us whether you want the result to be ordered (as in a list). Otherwise, what you are searching for is called a multiset.

Comment: it doesn't have to come out ordered, but I'd like to be able to order it at some point. I will look at multisets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
val data = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 2, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4), List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(2, 3, 4))

val map = data.map(_.groupBy(identity)).foldLeft(Map[Int, List[Int]]()) {
   case (r, c) => r ++ c.map {
       case (k, v) => k -> (if (v.size > r.getOrElse(k, List()).size) v else r(k))
}
}.values.flatten                               
//> map  : Iterable[Int] = List(2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3)
```

It does not maintain the ordering. After this you can call to sort this.

Maybe this is cleaner

```
data.flatMap(_.groupBy(identity)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.sortBy(_._2.size).reverse(0)._2).values.flatten
//> res0: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: thanks, these work. now i just need to look them over to understand what they're doing ;)

Comment: Lol..First one is easier to understand. Comment, if you need help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get it, but you can just order elements

```
data.flatten.sorted
```

Which would give you

```
List(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
```

if you want them ordered by number of encounters, you can do it like this:

```
data.flatten.groupBy(k => k).mapValues(_.size).toList.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
```

which would give you

```
List(1, 4, 2, 3)
```